# I'm having a problem with HTML in Google Sites

Tags: javascript, html, function, alert, google-sites

Because I don't understand Google Scripts, I use Google Sites, and when ever I try put this code in, nothing happens, so I used another piece of code that would tell me if it wasn't working, and it said "User canceled request", when you click the button, a drop down of updates, and upcoming updates should appear, but nothing happens.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Press for Announcements</button>
<script>
function myFunction(){
  alert("New:\n- New Code\n- Update Button\n- About the Creator Section\n- Contact the Creator\n\nComing Soon:\n- Quote Code YouTube Channel\n- More Codes\n- Accounts\n- Commenting\n- Pre-made Code\n- C/C++\n- Code Sandbox");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are unable to use alert dialogs in Google Sites. Google Scripts can be confusing. It's usually good to open up the web console as these errors should give you some idea of what is going on.

This change will add your text into a new DIV within the site. I imagine you want it to do much more, but hopefully this helps you understand what was going wrong.

```
<button onclick="createHTMLalert()">Press for Announcements</button>
<script>

    function createHTMLalert(){
        if(!document.getElementById('announcements_alert')){
            let announcements_alert = document.createElement('div');
            announcements_alert.id = 'announcements_alert';
            document.body.appendChild(announcements_alert);
            announcements_alert.innerText = "New:\n- New Code\n- Update Button\n- About the Creator Section\n- Contact the Creator\n\nComing Soon:\n- Quote Code YouTube Channel\n- More Codes\n- Accounts\n- Commenting\n- Pre-made Code\n- C++ and C for Game Making\n- Quote Code Twitter Page\n- Code Park";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to make it to where when you click it again, it disappears?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure if that would be the best user experience. I would probably just create a custom dialog box. Feel free to send me a direct message and we can take this off platform.
The code to delete the element on a user click would be `announcements_alert.addEventListener('click',()=> { announcements_alert.remove()});`

Comment: where would I send you a direct message? and where would this go in the code?